# Axiom system: something return the type

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

Here Axiom is a mathematical language, it is not a java Library. It is something as Maple or Mathematica.
Does it exist something return the type one object in Axiom in the way I can do something as

```
q1:= if typeOf q= bohType then 1 else 0
```

?
There is some place that list all Axiom types so I can write in above bohType the correct string?
Thank you

Seen nobody answer...
I did not find a way for know if types of 2 obj are equal, or if one obj has one assigned type; but rethink about it: I just want the difference among List and Stream, for the safety use the maxIndex function... It is easy explicitlyFinite? Is ok as arguments for list (where use maxIndex) and stream and return 0 if List, 1 for Streams (where there is not a max index so I can choose it) (at last it seems so). So resolved problem... Good morning...

Seen nobody answer I think I had found a workaround for this
It seems this function can find if the type is the same

```
f(a,b)==(if tex domainOf a=tex domainOf b then return 1 else return 0)
```

some test:

```
(5) -> f(a,b)==(if tex domainOf a=tex domainOf b then return 1 else return 0)
                                                               Type: Void
                                                              Time: 0 sec
(6) -> f(33, 99)
Compiling function f with type (PositiveInteger,PositiveInteger) ->
  NonNegativeInteger

(6)  1
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
                                   Time: 0.02 (IN) + 0.02 (EV) = 0.03 sec
(7) -> f(33, -99)
Compiling function f with type (PositiveInteger,Integer) ->
  NonNegativeInteger

(7)  0
                                                 Type: NonNegativeInteger
                                               Time: 0.02 (IN) = 0.02 sec
(8) -> f(4*x,x^2)
   Compiling function f with type (Polynomial Integer,Polynomial
   Integer) -> NonNegativeInteger

(8)  1
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
                                   Time: 0.03 (IN) + 0.10 (OT) = 0.13 sec
```

Comment: Please align the code part in question properly for better understanding

Comment: if typeOf(a)::String = "List" then 1 else 0.       not seems ok...